# How do I transform a 1 column data frame into a vector while the column name stays the vector name in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column and some rows which I want to transform into a vector. The name of the column should be the name of the vector as well. Usually, I create another object doing this:

```
new_object <- as.vector(df$variable_name)
new_object
```

Is there a way to keep the variable name as the name of the vector?

(I am asking as I try to build this in a function and need it therefore)

Thank you!

Comment: do you want the object to carry the name, e.g. when your df column is "test", then you want to create a vector called "test" or do you want a named vector, e.g. the vector could be called "xyz", but has a name attribute "test"?

Comment: If `varname <- "somename"`, then perhaps `assign(df[[varname]], varname)` will assign a variable named `"somename"` with the contents of `df$somename`.

Comment: The object should be named variable_name in this case and contains only the values like 1,0,0,0,1...

Comment: @r2evans I think the parameters in your assign code snippet should be the other way around, no?

Comment: @deschen, I wasn't sure, so I threw something out there hoping for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list2env` -

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)
a
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub <-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
n<-c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)

df <- data.frame(sub, n)

n <- df$n

[1] 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

You should be able to just simply call the variable name to get the vector.

Comment: Thank you, just hard to put it in a function then!

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))

assign(names(df), df[,1])

x
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Yes this way works too, thank you!

Comment: Then you might want to upvote it as a helpful answer. And then you can also accept one of the answers as your accepted one.

Comment: Did it. Had to wait some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

We could use `attach`

```
attach(df)
```

-output

```
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
```